# Simple C++ string formatting under GCC

Tags: c++, string, formatting

I am converting someone else's C++ library to work under GCC ([Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode)). What is the basic method for string formatting?

EDIT:  I see the original phrasing of my question caused a lot of confusion, not to mention some amusement.  What I need to do is replace certain string formatting functions in their library. They have done formatting via wxString, which I don't want to include in my project -- I know it is out there for Xcode, but that seems like a sledgehammer-type approach for the simple formatting I need to do.  They have functions which take their objects and spit out strings -- typically (char*), and I need to create the same (char*) outputs [which might then go to another object in the library; not necessarily to the user], but do it in a way that does not use wxString.  And I'd rather avoid turning it into C++.  In Objective-C, I do this all the time with [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)'s stringWithFormat: method. Obviously I don't want to use any NSString methods and don't want to create NSStrings.  Creating (char*) or C++ strings would be fine.  And no, it's not a false fact, and it's not homework.

Comment: He's asking for equivalent of that code in C++...

Comment: @Neil If it were C++ code, I suspect he wouldn't be asking the question. He's looking for how to convert that Objective-C into C++.

Comment: He said he was converting someone else's C++ library.

Comment: @Tony he states `someone else's _c++_ library`.

Comment: @Neil Hmmm, a true fact. Maybe the library was using some sort of weird custom string formatting? Either way, I don't really care all that much. Cheers.

Comment: @Neil You mean ObjectiveC library to C++.

Comment: @SIFE Somebody just did an unjustified edit. I've rolled it back. You should not make edits that change the sense of the question.

Comment: @Jonathan: Out of curiosity, what would be an example of a "false fact"? :-)

Comment: @Neil: Be polite. Why do you think it is wrong? Changing a meaning of introductory phrase to match a question itself and a code example William have provided is not wrong.

Comment: @Vlad - If he is using gcc with XCode he is on a Mac, so Objective-C would be just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use streams:

```
std::stringstream ss;

ss << somedouble << someint;
```

Comment: Heheh, beat me to it! :)

Comment: His format is scientific double (%g). I think your example will do a different conversion.

Comment: @Vlad, I guess then he'd have to create custom `operator <<` and `operator >>` overload

Comment: @Tony: I think that is not necessary as there are stream format modifiers like `std::hex` etc.

Comment: @phresnel: Right. I am just saying that providing exact equivalent will be much better. Dude doesn't know I/O streams or C++ whatsoever, so... I personally almost never use C++ i/o streams because I have a strong believe that they suck, so I can't throw any examples from top of my head.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenok: Though once you understand the impact of type safety and software security, C-format-strings suck more than iostreams. Also, I fear you must be using them wrong; they are extensible upon your own types, so e.g. you can do "MyAwesomeFoo foo, bar; cout << (foo * bar) << '\n';", which is far less tedious than C-like approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use the printf family of functions, but in 99.99% of cases, this is heavily frowned upon for very good reason.

See Tony The Tiger's answer.

---

edit: Okay. Why the frowning upon format strings.

- How do you printf your own types or types from some 3rd party C++ library? Unlike printf, streams are extensible:

  `cout << foo << '\n';`

  vs

  ```
  printf ("%s: %f %f %f / scc(%d)\n", 
   foo.name(), 
   foo.height(), foo.width(), foo.depth(),
   foo.sampleCount());
  ```
- oh crap, passing non-POD types to varargs yields undefined behaviour; guess what `foo.name()`'s return type is? Funnily, it compiles fine, and depending on the implementation, might even work for some strange reason.
- After a while, I begin to use my own non-primitive `Decimal`-implementation, to be used as return-type by `foo.width()/height()/depth()`. Crappily crap, now I invoke undefined behaviour 4 times in that line alone.
- How do I avoid format-string redundancy? Shall I externalize printing like this:

```
printf("foo is:"); 
   printFoo (stdout); 
   printf("\n");
```

- lastly, I've had a bad day and a bad night. I type: `float f; fscanf(stdout, "%c %f", f);` -> Please find all errors.

Comment: Frown all you like... I've personally also tried to be good and use `<iomanip>`, but come on, the sheer amount of verbosity to express a simple format that's required at times... if you know what data types you're dealing with, a quick use of `*printf` can be a total lifesaver.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: come on ...
a) How do you printf your own types or types from some 3rd party C++ library? Unlike printf, streams are extensible: `MyAwesomeFoo foo, bar; cout << foo << '\n';` sucks really more than `printf ("%s: %f %f %f / scc(%d)\n", foo.name(), foo.height(), foo.width(), foo.depth(), foo.sampleCount());`, really?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: b) oh crap, passing non-POD types to varargs yields undefined behaviour; guess what foo.name()'s return type is? Funnily, it even compilers, and depending on the implementation, might even work for some strange reason.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: c) After a while, I begin to use my own non-primitive Decimal-implementation, to be used as return-type by foo.width()/height()/depth(). Crappily crap, now I invoke undefined behaviour 4 times in that line alone.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: d) How do I avoid format-string redundancy? Shall I externalize printing like this: `printf("foo is:"); printFoo (stdout); printf("\n");`. How non-tedious.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: e) lastly, I've had a bad day and a bad night. I type: `float f; scanf("%c %f", f);` ... So yeah, come on.

Comment: @phresnel: It's all situational. Of course there's lots of beauty in overloading your own stream operations. But when you're trying to print out a hex dump of memory content (e.g. while debugging a long double ULP-comparison), I can gladly write printf-%02X-output today for something you'll still be setw/setfill/uppercase/hex-ing tomorrow :-) Situational. (Don't forget to std::dec back, too, at the next unpredictable program flow point!)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Well you wrote printf can be a lifesaver, but actually that breed is among the number one security problems, therefore possibly a killer. Agree on situational, but your quick hexdump is just the 0.01% of use cases, and typically such things are not exposed to end users.

Comment: @phresnet: I guess a steel boot can be a lifesaver to a builder and useless to a fashion model... and I do have a [vested interest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) in `operator<<`! :-) I just find it curious that formatted printing of simple data types can be such a pain in C++... thanks for updating the post though!

Comment: @phresnet: I certainly share no commensurate love for `fscanf`, so don't put that in my mouth :-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: From the formatting standpoint, format strings are all fine and iostreams are not. It is really the security and extensibility that make them suck less :)

Comment: @phresnet: I agree. That's why I had heavily mixed output code in the past, but I'm now sticking to pure C++ iostreams, even though I sometimes fill a screen with a simple debug output code!

Answer (score 1):

[`sprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) is a good starting point. However, it really depends on what you wan't to achieve. `std::stringstream` is a good alternative as Tony The Tiger points out, [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/format/) is another.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing it in C++. For example:

```
char str[256];
snprintf (str, sizeof (str), "%g %d %s", someDouble, someInteger, someString);
```

You can also print directly to some output stream, use C++ I/O streams, even to the degree of [Boost.LexicalCast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).